# How can I install Windows on my MacBook without a working dvd drive?

Tags: mac, multi-boot, netboot

I've got netboot set up on my Mac mini, but I can't figure out how to get it to serve my Windows XP iso file.  I guess my question can go either way:

How do I get NetBoot on my Mac mini to serve the Windows XP iso over netboot

or

How do I install Windows as a dual boot on my Mac mini without a working dvd drive?

Comment: www.instructables.com/id/Make-Your-Regular-Mac-a-NetBoot-Server!/step13/Build-A-NetBoot-Image-From-A-Bootable-CD/

Comment: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=816452 http://www.bukisa.com/articles/265078_how-to-really-enable-dvd-drive-sharing-on-a-non-air-macbook These should help! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't mention which version of Windows, but I'm guessing Windows 7. There's a [nifty little tool to do it with a USB drive here](http://www.askvg.com/a-bootable-usb-utility-to-create-bootable-usb-drive-to-install-windows-vista-server-2008-and-7/). Requires a Windows PC to make the bootable thumb drive though.

Comment: I've done this using Microsoft's tool, and it works well.

Comment: The question was for XP, but that was a long time ago.  Accepting this as the answer as I'd rather install 7 than XP (who wouldn't?) now.

Answer (score -1):

Simple Answer you can't use Netboot as it only supports Mac OS X.
Easiest way would be to use a USB CD Drive, if you'll be mass deploying it the take a look at Deploy Studio.

But if you're comfortable with Visualization then you can use the remote disc function of mac os x in conjunction with VMware Fusion.

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1131